# Wait for some threads to be in wait state in order to continue

Tags: java, multithreading

I got group of threads that are doing some work and then are staying in a wait state (waiting for notify). I want to run a new thread doing some other work just after all the group of threads I mentioned above became to be in  a wait state.
I was thinking if there is a way to do it without adding some logic inside the code that those group of threads are running, and maybe there is a simple way solve it in the code that start those threads (in other words in the main thread).
if not, what do you think is simple way to solve this problem

Comment: The only way I can think of is having a global singleton which you register your threads on at the start. Then, adding a listener starts a thread that continuelly loops and checks the list of threads untill they all are in the wait state, but as you mentioned, it does use some logic.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully, this is what I get from what you're saying... You want to perform some task while all the threads are in a waiting state or you want to perform a task before all threads are finished?

Comment: There is a way to make all threads wait, at some point, on each other. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Ryan_DS       
do you think that semaphore can help to solve it? (in case I know the number of threads that wait for them to be in a wait state)

Comment: @chinloyal     
I sorry you don't understand me, my English is not so good. i meant that I got number of the threads that I know that will in some point in wait state. I want to know when all all of them came to the point that they are is wait state.

Comment: I meant to just get a list of threads you want to check, then on another thread, check every few ms if they are in the waiting state or not. @chinloyal

Comment: @Ryan_DS oh sorry my comment was aimed at the OP

Comment: usually a thread is allowed to work after receiving some information or explicit permission (via Semaphore). Here you interpret the fact that some set of threads got into wait state as a permission for other thread to run. This is a bad idea because such dependence is implicit. If you manage to solve this task, some time later this solution can become a source of trouble. I recommend to use explicit synchronization mechanism - Semaphore of CountDownlatch.